# Bulk create with multi-table inheritance models

Tags: python, django

I'm using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) models.

```py
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Cinema(Place):
    sells_tickets = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sells_popcorn = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Coffee(Place):
    sells_tea = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have a view that creates several different models:

```py
items = [
    Restaurant(...),
    Restaurant(...),
    Restaurant(...),
    Cinema(...),
    Cinema(...),
    Coffee(...),
    Coffee(...),
    # + 1.000 other items
]
for item in items:
    item.save()
```

Obviously, this is really inefficient since it creates a lot of queries. Unfortunately, Django doesn't provide a bulk-create method for multi-table inheritance yet (there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/13763) for it). What is the best way to optimize this code? Do I have to write a raw SQL query or is there another way?

Comment: refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: @harshilsuthar Please read the question in full. OP already stated that he researched his options and that bulk_create does not work for his use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by inspecting the implementation of [`bulk_create`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/query.py#L455). Underlying it uses the [`InsertQuery`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py#L137) class to generate the SQL `INSERT INTO` statement. IMHO this is much cleaner and shorter than writing a raw SQL query.

```py
# Create all concrete models at once
items = Place.objects.bulk_create(items)

# Group items by their model
item_mapping = defaultdict(list)
for item in items:
    item_mapping[type(item)].append(item)

# Create a bulk insert for each model
for model, items in item_mapping.items():
    fields = model._meta.local_concrete_fields
    query = sql.InsertQuery(model)
    query.insert_values(fields, items)
    query.get_compiler(connection=connection).execute_sql()
```

Comment: Hi. Only works for PostgreSQL, because other database engines do not return objects with generated primary keys as return from bulk_create. It Will only work if you explicitly define a primary key for the parent model and handle primary keys manually.